# Fastlane doesn't work in MacOS Ventura 13.1 (M1)

Tags: android, homebrew, apple-m1, fastlane, macos-ventura

When executing fastlane command in terminal, it shows the follow errors in MacOS 13.1 running on M1 chips

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem fastlane (>= 0.a) with executable fastlane (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

How to solve it?

fastlane is supposed to work as normal

Answer (score 2):

## Trials

According to the fastlane setup guideline https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/setup/, fastlane relies on the ruby + bundler but the system ruby is not recommended.

Thus, to install Ruby in another project scope instead of modifying the system environment, I tried install ruby 3.2.0 via [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and [ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build).

However, it failed and the ruby version is different from the system installed one. I get the ruby version by executing

```
$ruby -v 
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]
```

## Solution

Another approach is to install the fastlane by Homebrew

It showed another error as below :

> Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
> Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
> "Alternative Installs" from:
> https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
> You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
> brew bundle dump

Currently my homebrew is in

```
$which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

As a result, the idea to solve this issue is reinstall the homebrew in `/opt/homebrew` direction.

### Step 1 : Install Homebrew for your MacOS

Running this command,

```
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

followed by the steps in [homebrew install guide](https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/3.html)

### Step 2 : Set your default Homebrew to `/opt/homebrew`

I'm using zsh terminal, so just need to add a new eval config in your zsh config file.

```
$echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

You can see Homebrew path has been changed when reopen your zsh terminal.

```
$which brew
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
```

### Step 3 : Run brew install fastlane

```
$brew install fastlane
```

Fastlane works again!